# Finding sums of magic square cells (The “magic square” of the Sagrada Familia)

Tags: equation-solving, cells

**Update**

Finally got the [background](http://staybarcelonaapartments.com/blog/magic-square-sagrada-familia/) origin of this. And a more comprehensive article is [here](https://blog.sagradafamilia.org/en/divulgation/the-magic-square-the-passion-facade-keys-to-understanding-it/). This has **has a total of 310 combinations that add up to 33.**

And this **IS** more interesting way of highlighting.
[image]

**OP**

Saw this math puzzle on Twitter, which asks with the given magic square to find 33 different ways of adding 4 of its cells to 33.

[image]

I tried to use `Solve`

```
Solve[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 == 33 && x1 < x2 < x3 < x4, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, { x1, x2, x3, x4} ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15}]


Solve[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 == 33 && x1 < x2 < x3 < x4, {
  x1 ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15},
  x2 ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15},
  x3 ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15},
  x4 ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15}
  }
 ]
```

Neither worked.

2nd problem is how to use the solutions to highlight it like in the graph?
Should be easy after we obtain all solutions. Something like

```
m = {
  {1, 14, 14, 4},
  {11, 7, 6, 9},
  {8, 10, 10, 5},
  {13, 2, 3, 15}
  }

Grid[m /. {"answers"}, Frame -> All]
```

Thanks.

Comment: does this help in any way: `Sort/@Select[DuplicateFreeQ]@IntegerPartitions[33, {4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15}]`

Comment: @AntonAntonov Sorry. I saw this last night just before I went to bed. It's meant to be a maths puzzle, where the `magic square` has 33 different ways of adding 4 numbers to 33. Couldn't find the OP now.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Please review my edit of the question.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks. I have also added a bit background information to this.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Great, very nice!

Comment: @AntonAntonov This is more comprehensive. https://blog.sagradafamilia.org/en/divulgation/the-magic-square-the-passion-facade-keys-to-understanding-it/

Comment: If you remember the link I provided on your last question like this I think GalAster has a solution programmed up for this one too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
domain = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15};
```

#### Pick + Subsets

```
answers1 = Pick[s = Subsets[domain, {4}], s.{1,1,1,1}, 33];
```

#### IntegerPartitions

```
answers2 = Sort/@Select[DuplicateFreeQ]@IntegerPartitions[33, {4}, domain]
```

#### Solve

```
xx = Array[x, {14}];
answers3 = DeleteCases[#, 0, 2] &[domain  xx /. 
  Solve[{33 == xx.domain, Total[xx] == 4, ## & @@ Thread[0 <= xx <= 1]}, xx, Integers]]
```

#### Reduce

```
answers4 = DeleteCases[#, 0, 2] &[domain xx /. List[ToRules @ 
  Reduce[{xx. domain == 33, Total[xx] == 4, ## & @@ Thread[0 <= xx <= 1]},  xx, Integers]]
```

#### FrobeniusSolve

```
answers5 = DeleteCases[domain # & /@ 
    Select[FrobeniusSolve[domain, 33], Max[#] == 1 && Total[#] == 4 &], 0, 2] ;


Sort@answers1 == Sort@answers2 == Sort@answers3 == Sort@answers4 == Sort@answers5
```

> True

#### Highlighting

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/O55Kb.png"]
```

[image]

```
Grid @ Partition[ImageMultiply[img, 
   MatrixPlot[m , DataReversed -> False,Frame -> True, Mesh -> All, 
     FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> 1 -> 10, 
     ColorRules -> { ## & @@ Map[# -> Orange &, #, {-1}], _ :>  White}]] & /@ answers1, 8]
```

[image]

```
Grid @ Partition[Grid[m /. Map[# -> Item[#, Background -> Orange] &, #, {-1}], 
     Dividers -> All] & /@ answers1, 8]
```

[image]

**Update:** Highlighting only 4 elements (ignoring one of the duplicate elements):

```
Grid @ Partition[ImageMultiply[img, 
  MatrixPlot[MapAt[Orange &, m, Position[m, #, 2, 1][[1]] & /@ #] ,
    DataReversed -> False, Frame -> True, Mesh -> All, 
    FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> 1 -> 10, 
    ColorRules -> { _ :> White}]] & /@ answers1, 8]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solutions contains the cases where five (repeated ones) numbers were used?

Comment: Thanks. I had added a bit background to this now. It does not seem to be "magic" to be at all. To start with, MMA found many more solutions then the `given` solutions. Secondly, the numbers in the matrix does not follow any pattern. It's just some "random" combinations.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu, so `realanswers = Table[RandomSample[domain, 4],  28]`? :)

Comment: I have no idea, see my updated post with the new image. I am just doing background reading on this now, to see what's so special about it.

Comment: https://blog.sagradafamilia.org/en/divulgation/the-magic-square-the-passion-facade-keys-to-understanding-it/

Comment: @Chen, very interesting indeed. here is one more: `Length@Subsets[Range@14,{4}] == 1001`:)

Comment: My maths isn't particularly good, and I might have missed something. Why is it `Range@14` and not `Range@15` ?

Comment: @Chen , `Length@domain ==14`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79638/discussion-between-chen-stats-yu-and-kglr).

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {{1, 14, 14, 4}, {11, 7, 6, 9}, {8, 10, 10, 5}, {13, 2, 3, 15}};
Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@m
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15}

To find the solutions:

```
sol = Sort /@ Select[#, DuplicateFreeQ[#] &] & @
        IntegerPartitions[33, {4}, Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@m];
Length@sol
```

> 48

(or with [kglr's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176414/solve-by-defining-specific-integer-domain-set#comment462973_176414) `Sort/@Select[DuplicateFreeQ]@IntegerPartitions[33, {4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15}]`

and then

```
Grid@Partition[MatrixForm[m /. (# -> Highlighted[#] & /@ #)] & /@ sol, 6, 6]
```

[image]

`10` and `14` appear twice in `m`. To neglect one of them in `Highlight`ing, I employ a rather crude approach of changing one of the `10`s and `14`s to `10.` and `14.`, `Highlight`ing and the `Rationalize`ing:

```
pos10 = Position[m, 10]
pos14 = Position[m, 14]
m2 = ReplacePart[m, {pos10[[1]] -> 10., pos14[[1]] -> 14.}];
```

so for example

```
MatrixForm[m2 /. (# -> Highlighted[#] & /@ sol[[1]])]
```

[image]

Hence

```
Grid@Partition[MatrixForm[Rationalize[m2 /. (# -> Highlighted[#] & /@ #)]] & /@ sol, 6, 6]
```

[image]

Changing the `Part`s in `m2` one can obtain the `Highlight`ings for the other three cases.